# How to omit comfirmation when I compile the files in emacs?

Tags: compiling, emacs

When I update my document and compile it, I will experience as follows:

```
Save file /home/*****/test2.tex? (y or n)  y
command: (default LaTeX) LateX
```

I want them to perform default. And not show those two lines. How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: These are two different questions, really. It would be easiest to just define a new function to save the current buffer and run TeX-command-master immediately afterward.

Comment: By the way, you can just press enter (or C-m) for the second one.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, that's what I do, press Y and then enter. But what I want is that it can automatically compile without any confirmation when I just use C-c C-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lisp
(defun yuxuan-save-and-compile (extended)
  "Save and run the default command.
With a prefix argument, just run `TeX-command-master'."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-buffer)
  (if extended (call-interactively #'TeX-command-master)
    (TeX-command TeX-command-default #'TeX-master-file nil)))
```

Bind to whatever key you think is appropriate.  With a prefix argument, this will call the normal command for C-c C-c, `TeX-command-master`.