# how to make (TeX-command-run-all) save automatically without asking?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have just upgraded to `AUCTeX 11.89.1` in emacs and find the new command `(TeX-command-run-all)` quite convenient. One problem is that after modifying the file and typing `C-c C-a`, confirmation is needed to save the file first.

I suspect that I kind of only need to set something to `nil` to deactivate this confirmation step, but I have not found a way. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: The file has to be saved. Do you mean to automatically save before running `TeX-command-run-all`?

Comment: @jon, yes, I want to save automatically on compiling. I think a short sequential lisp function would do, but i hope there is more direct way.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate. `TeX-save-query` is news to me, though :) [How to omit comfirmation when I compile the files in emacs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260942/17423)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The variable [`TeX-save-query`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dsave_002dquery) controls this behavior:

> *User Option*: `TeX-save-query`
>
> If non-nil, then query the user before saving each file with `TeX-save-document`.

Add the following line to your init file

```lisp
(setq TeX-save-query nil)
```

Comment: Is this a trap? If Emacs does not ask, the users will not save the file and TeX will run on the saved, old version?

Comment: It'll always save without asking, that's exactly what davyjones is looking after.

Comment: OK, »my« solution works with all Emacs buffers, while this here is AUCTeX specific.

Comment: @KeksDose Which is exactly why it scares me :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lisp package, auto-save-buffers.el

Put into your .emacs:

```
(require 'auto-save-buffers)
(run-with-idle-timer 2 t 'auto-save-buffers)
(global-set-key [f8] 'auto-save-buffers-toggle)
```

»2«: seconds between stop typing and saving

»f8« toggle the function.

Comment: Unless you're always on some version control system, actually saving all the time seems like it could backfire on you pretty badly.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to automatically save the buffer before evaluating `TeX-command-run-all`. The below simply adds a `(save-buffer)` prior to doing everything that the original `TeX-command-run-all` does, and then binds the new command over the original interactive key sequence.

```
(defun save-and-TeX-command-run-all (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (save-buffer)
  (cond
   ((null arg)       (TeX-command-sequence t t))
   ((= 4 (car arg))  (TeX-command-run-all-region))
   (t                (LaTeX-command-run-all-section))))

(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-a") 'save-and-TeX-command-run-all)
```